# Microblaze interrupt example with freeRTOS giving multiple definition of _interrupt_handler

Tags: c, microblaze

I have created a simple example program with the Xilinx SDK that has FreeRTOS and I am running into an issue which seems quite unexpected.  I want to fire an software interrupt and so I have set up the code this way.

```
void software_test( void ) __attribute__((interrupt_handler));

void software_test( void )
{
   // clear the interrupt
   *((volatile uint32_t *) 0x4120000C) = 0x80;
   interrupt_occurred++;
}
```

When I try to compile it complains about:

```
\interrupt_example_bsp\microblaze_0\libsrc\freertos823_xilinx_v1_1\src/portasm.S:288: multiple definition of `_interrupt_handler'
./src/freertos_hello_world.o:\Debug/../src/freertos_hello_world.c:130: first defined here
```

I checked portasm.S and it has the following code in it:

```
.global _interrupt_handler

... bunch more unreleated code here

.text
.align  4
_interrupt_handler:

portSAVE_CONTEXT

/* Stack the return address. */
swi r14, r1, portR14_OFFSET

/* Switch to the ISR stack. */
lwi r1, r0, pulISRStack

/* The parameter to the interrupt handler. */
ori r5, r0, configINTERRUPT_CONTROLLER_TO_USE

/* Execute any pending interrupts. */
bralid r15, XIntc_DeviceInterruptHandler
or r0, r0, r0

/* See if a new task should be selected to execute. */
lwi r18, r0, ulTaskSwitchRequested
or r18, r18, r0

/* If ulTaskSwitchRequested is already zero, then jump straight to
restoring the task that is already in the Running state. */
beqi r18, task_switch_not_requested

/* Set ulTaskSwitchRequested back to zero as a task switch is about to be
performed. */
swi r0, r0, ulTaskSwitchRequested

/* ulTaskSwitchRequested was not 0 when tested.  Select the next task to
execute. */
bralid r15, vTaskSwitchContext
or r0, r0, r0

... bunch more code here
```

I am unclear how to fix this, has anyone else encountered this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look [at this discussion](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Development-Tools/multiple-definition-of-interrupt-handler/td-p/343453)

Comment: I have gone through that previously, my linker script was also generated by the wizard but it doesnt have xilkernel,  I have -Wl,--start-group,-lxil,-lfreertos,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information on implementing a Microblaze ISR using FreeRTOS: http://www.freertos.org/RTOS-Xilinx-Microblaze-KC705.html#implementing_an_ISR